# C#, While Loop, Try Catch, Log, Continue

Tags: c#, logging, while-loop, try-catch, continue

I'm writing a mobile application that will actually be running as a Task in ArcGIS, but my question is basically C# error handling. I'm using a `while` loop to loop through records and using `StreamWriter` to log a failed attempt to read the data. I've broken each field into its own seperate `try` `catch` so that I can write which record and which field caused the failure to the log file. Example below.

```
try
{
    TrafficLanesCount = Convert.ToByte(ModifiedFDR.GetValue(ModifiedFDR.GetOrdinal("TRAFICLN")));
}
catch
{
    sw.WriteLine(DOTNumber + " " + "TrafficLanesCount");
}
```

I'm saving at the end of the while loop, but if anything fails, I want to log it, skip that record, and continue on with the next record. Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: what do you mean by saying you save at the end? Close the stream?

Comment: We probably could use more of your while loop to offer ideas

Comment: Could you provide the whole code fragment with loop?

Comment: If that's in a `while` loop and after you hit an error you want to continue, then I would think you'd just use `continue;` in the `catch`.  But really it's hard to say without seeing more of the code and getting more details.

Comment: After I get all of these values to local variables, I'm calling a service to save at the bottom of this loop.

Comment: i suppose you rephrase your qustion. it is kind of unclear what you expect/what is the current behavior...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
sw.WriteLine(DOTNumber + " " + "TrafficLanesCount");
```

You could use

```
File.AppendAllText("path/to/log.txt", DOTNumber + " " + "TrafficLanesCount" + nvironment.NewLine);
```

To write the lines in realtime. This way, your logs would be persisted within every catch..

I also want to point out, that there are very mature Frameworks for Logging. For example [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) or [Log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/) to name two of the more popular ones.

Answer (score 0):

Using the code provided, I would go with something like this:

```
var errorList = new List<Exception>();
foreach(var record in records)
{
    try 
    {
        try
        {
            TrafficLanesCount = Convert.ToByte(ModifiedFDR.GetValue(ModifiedFDR.GetOrdinal("TRAFICLN")));
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new Exception(new string(DOTNumber + " " + "TrafficLanesCount"));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        errorList.Add(exp);
    }
}
```

And afterwords, you can loop through the exceptions in the list and handle them at that point.

Comment: It makes little sense to catch your own exception.  The inner try..catch is redundant.  Just let any exception bubble up.